# Calculate duration in years if months increases from 12 months

Tags: sql-server

I have a column that accepts values in NoOfMonths which I want to calculate in years. My table structure let's say is given below

```
CREATE TABLE Duration
(
TotalMonths int
);

INSERT INTO Duration VALUES (24);
INSERT INTO Duration VALUES (18);
INSERT INTO Duration VALUES (7);
```

I want the result to be shown like this,

```
Months  Duration
24      2 Years
18      1 Year 6 Months
7       7 Months
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN TotalMonths>12
          THEN CAST(TotalMonths/12 AS VARCHAR(10))+' Years '
       ELSE '' END
    +
    CASE WHEN TotalMonths%12>0
          THEN CAST(TotalMonths%12 AS VARCHAR(10))+' Months'
       ELSE '' END
    FROM Duration
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the data like this

```
select duration,
       duration / 12 as years,
       duration % 12 as months
from your_table
```

You should do the rest in the presentation layer of your program.

Comment: @Shnugo I did not know it was a speed contest :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
DECLARE @Duration TABLE(TotalMonths int);

INSERT INTO @Duration VALUES (24),(18),(7);

SELECT d.TotalMonths
      ,A.*
      , CASE WHEN A.CountYears>0 THEN CAST (A.CountYears AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' years ' ELSE '' END 
      + CASE WHEN A.CountMonths>0 THEN CAST(A.CountMonths AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' months' ELSE '' END AS TextDescription
FROM @Duration AS d
CROSS APPLY(SELECT d.TotalMonths / 12 AS CountYears
                  ,d.TotalMonths % 12 AS CountMonths) AS A;
```

Edited to using `modulo operator %`

The result

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------------+
| TotalMonths | CountYears | CountMonths | TextDescription  |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------------+
| 24          | 2          | 0           | 2 years          |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------------+
| 18          | 1          | 6           | 1 years 6 months |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------------+
| 7           | 0          | 7           | 7 months         |
+-------------+------------+-------------+------------------+
```

Hint: The integer division will silently round to integer values.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that like this :

```
declare @Duration table (TotalMonths int)

INSERT INTO @Duration VALUES (24), (18), (7)

select d.TotalMonths as months, 
       case when d.TotalMonths / 12 > 0 then convert(varchar, d.TotalMonths / 12) + ' years ' else '' end
       +
       case when d.TotalMonths % 12 > 0 then convert(varchar, d.TotalMonths % 12) + ' Months' else '' end 
       as Duration
from   @Duration d
```

the result is

```
months  Duration    
------  --------    
24      2 years     
18      1 years 6 Months    
7       7 Months
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how to display a dummy column, and do the math in it.
something like this

```
select TotalMonths, ((select TotalMonths from Duration) / 12) As DurationInYears from Duration
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple way that you can convert an integer value into month and days:

```
SELECT Duration(dd,366,0)
```

this will convert duration value into months and years.